# Настройка разлиных flavour в gradle-файле Андроид проекта

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle

Не получается перенастроить gradle под новые требования.

Обновил плагин gradle и поломалась система построения разных сборок.

Было:
1) в src сделаны три папки

- `src/main` с общиими файлами
- `src/stagingEnvironment` с файлами для стейджа, в том числе манифест
- `src/productionEnvironment` с файлами для прода, в том числе манифест

2) в `app/gradle`

2.1) настройка ресурсов:

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }

        stagingEnvironment {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/stagingEnvironment/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/stagingEnvironment/res']
            manifest.srcFile manifestStagingPath
            jniLibs.srcDir jniLibsPath
        }

        productionEnvironment {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/productionEnvironment/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/productionEnvironment/res']
            manifest.srcFile manifestProductionPath
            jniLibs.srcDir jniLibsPath
        }
    }
```

2.2) настройка флаворов:

```
productFlavors {
        stagingEnvironment {
            applicationId 'com.example'
            versionCode Integer.valueOf(StagingVersionCode)
            versionName StagingVersionName
        }

        productionEnvironment {
            applicationId 'com.example'
            versionCode Integer.valueOf(ProductionVersionCode)
            versionName ProductionVersionName
        }
    }
```

2.3) настройка типов сборок

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), defProguardFiles
        }
    }
```

Соответственно, в панели выбора build variants я видел

- stagingEnvironmentDebug
- stagingEnvironmentRelease
- productionEnvironmentDebug
- productionEnvironmentRelease

===================================

После обновления плагина, появилась ошибка `Error:All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension.` По аналогии с [документацией](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration?utm_source=android-studio#variant_aware) я  добавил
`flavorDimensions "dev", "prod"` а в блоках фловоров эти названия:

```
productFlavors {
        stagingEnvironment {
            applicationId 'com.example'
            versionCode Integer.valueOf(StagingVersionCode)
            versionName StagingVersionName
            dimension 'dev'
        }

        productionEnvironment {
            applicationId 'com.example'
            versionCode Integer.valueOf(ProductionVersionCode)
            versionName ProductionVersionName
            dimension 'prod'
        }
    }
```

Проблема 1:
в панели выбора build variants теперь есть только два варианта "смердженных"
stagingEnvironmentProductionEnvironmentDebug
stagingEnvironmentProductionEnvironmentRelease
 **- как сделать, чтобы они не мерджились между собой?**

Проблема 2: (наверное, вытекает из первой) - при попытке сборки пишет *Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал. Выяснилось, чтобы флаворы не мерджили между собой, им необходимо давать одно и то же dimension.

Вот полностью рабочий код c разбитием приложения на два environment.

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/common/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/common/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/common/assets']
            manifest.srcFile manifestCommonPath
        }

        devServer {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/devServer/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/devServer/res']
            manifest.srcFile manifestStagingPath
            jniLibs.srcDir jniLibsPath
        }

        prodServer {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/prodServer/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/prodServer/res']
            manifest.srcFile manifestProductionPath
            jniLibs.srcDir jniLibsPath
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "environment"

    productFlavors {
        devServer {
            applicationId 'com.example'
            versionCode Integer.valueOf(StagingVersionCode)
            versionName StagingVersionName
            dimension 'environment'
        }

        prodServer {
            applicationId 'com.example'
            versionCode Integer.valueOf(ProductionVersionCode)
            versionName ProductionVersionName
            dimension 'environment'
        }
    }
```

Общие файлы лежат в src/common. Файлы которые используются в дев сервере (манифест, стринг и всё такое) - в src/devServer, а для прода - src/prodServer. Если интересно полный код гредла, то вот [гист](https://gist.github.com/andrewgrow/f7906bd85e9600a4379170faba1ff683). Удачной разработки! )